# Adding user defined headers in wso2 esb custom proxy

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have created a custom proxy for a given address endpoint. The custom proxy exposes the methods which are there in the actual endpoint. However I wanted the custom proxy to expose some custom headers in the SOAP header to the end user. The end user would then pass the data in these custom headers and these values would be used in the mediation logic.  How would I do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To manipulate header values, you can add a Header mediator (Transform->Header) in the in/out sequences. Use a Property mediator(Core->Property) to set/remove property values in the message context. These can be retrieved by get-property(proerty-name) later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use script mediators to carry out mediation on the message headers. You can extract message headers using the following code

`<property name="authheader" expression="get-property('transport','Accept')"/>`

Answer (score 0):

In the wsdl, you can add soap:header elements, that are transmitted inside the Header element of the SOAP Envelope.  I believe you have a custom wsdl, which is exposed via the proxy..So you can edit that..